# Convert from Iterable to Page Object

Tags: java, spring, couchbase

I have a method which returns all the documents found in the couchbase repo and the result is a `Page<MyObject>` object which is fine:

```
...
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;

  Page<MyObject> myObjects = myRepo
      .findAll(new PageRequest(page == null ? 0 : page, size));
...
```

And I have another method which returns a `Iterable<MyObject>` as you can see below. The method is working fine and the results retrieved from couchbase are ok.

```
...
  Bucket myBucket = myRepo.getCouchbaseOperations().getCouchbaseBucket();
  PrefixQuery field = SearchQuery.prefix(searchParameter);

  SearchQueryResult searchQueryResult = myBucket
    .query(new SearchQuery("text-search", field)
    .fields("name").explain());

  List <String> idList = new ArrayList<>();
  for (SearchQueryRow searchQueryRow : searchQueryResult.hits()) {
    idList.add(searchQueryRow.id());
  }

  Iterable<MyObject> myObjects = myRepo.findAll(idList);
...
```

My question is: How can I convert `Iterable<MyObject> myObjects` into a `Page<MyObject> myObjects`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found how to do it, I'm posting the answer in case it can help anyone in the future. I achieved it by doing:

```
Iterable<MyObject> myObjects = myRepo.findAll(idList);
List<MyObject> myObjectsList = IteratorUtils.toList(myObjects.iterator());
Page<MyObject> myObjectsPage = new PageImpl<MyObject>(
                                     myObjectsList,
                                     new PageRequest(page, size), 
                                     myObjectsList.size());
```

Comment: I honestly disapprove of this because if the DB returns 10k `MyObjects` then you'd actually be storing the 10k of them into a list in memory. A page is supposed to be streamed through though instead =/